# Why isnt the collection being set in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

What is wrong with the following code?

```
var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {

    }
});

var List = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Item
});

var collection = new List({'variable':this}); //collection is NOT null!
var result = new Item({'collection':collection}); //result.collection is undefined! why?
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `defaults: {}` declaration?

Comment: @Dogbert didnt change anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your item to the list

```
var collection=new List,
result=new Item({ name: 'my item'});
collection.add( result );
```

or

```
collection.create({ name: 'my item'});
```

Comment: A collections constructor expects an array of objects as its first param. You gave it an object.

Comment: Then you access the collection property of your item directly. You have to use the .get('propertyname ') method of your model to get its value.